# How can I make ng-click work in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I added some ng-click events for buttons but when I try to click buttons, test() function won't fire. I did everything to fix that but I couldn't.

```xml
<div ng-controller="bilgiyarismasiCtrl" ng-repeat="x in sorular">
    <div class="row text-center" style="margin: 50px 250px 50px 250px;">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:90px; background-color:gray; color:white;">
            {{ x.SORU_ICERIGI }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:50px; background-color:white;">
            <button ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{ x.A_SIKKI }}</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:50px; background-color:white;">
            <button ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{ x.B_SIKKI}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

Angular code:

```js
var app = angular.module("module", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "bilgiyarismasi.html",
            controller: "bilgiyarismasiCtrl"
        });
});

app.controller("bilgiyarismasiCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("http://localhost:53438/api/BilgiYarismasi/GetSorular")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.sorular = response.data;
        });

    $scope.test = function () {
        console.log(1)
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Your code above is not invoking controller, due to this you are not able get output by clicking on any of your buttons.

Use below code :

```js
var ngApp = angular.module('app', []);

    
ngApp.controller('bilgiyarismasiCtrl',function($scope, $http){
$scope.sorular = [];
 /* $http.get("http://localhost:53438/api/BilgiYarismasi/GetSorular")
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.sorular = response.data;
            }); */
    $scope.test = function () {
            console.log('test')
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="bilgiyarismasiCtrl">
        <div >
        
         <div class="row text-center" style="margin: 50px 250px 50px 250px;">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:90px; background-color:gray; color:white;">
            {{ x.SORU_ICERIGI }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:50px; background-color:white;">
            <button ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{ 'x.A_SIKKI' }}</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding:50px; background-color:white;">
            <button ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{' x.B_SIKKI'}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have not included ng-app in your template file.
I have created a demo, can you please have a look.
Hope this helps you.